# Swift function - pass optional object

Tags: ios, function, swift, parameters

So I'm trying to call the function "submitBoilerPlate" in Swift:

```
var url:String = "https://eamorr.com/ajax/getLatestContent.php"
var params = [
   "hello":"world"
]
submitBoilerPlate(url, _params:params, _button:nil)
```

And here is the corresponding function:

```
func submitBoilerPlate(_url:String, _params:[String: String!], _button:UIButton?){
    var oldTitle = _button?.titleLabel?.text

    _button?.setTitle("Please wait...", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    _button?.enabled = false
    //etc.
    ...
}
```

Everything works as expected when I send a real UIButton that's declared on my xib.

However, I want to be able to send a "nil" button (this particular xib doesn't have a button).

Is this possible? Or do I have to have create a new function? I'm trying to keep code repetition to a minimum...

I get the following run-time error when the code gets to submitBoilerPlate(...):

`fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with `UIButton?` but with `_params:[String: String!]` if you are using it somewhere below in submitBoilerPlate function . Try replacing it with `_params:[String: String]`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. It's just the run-time error had the "nil" part of "_button:nil" highlighted.

Comment: @Eamorr He solved your problem. He deserves an accepted answer

Comment: Though what happens if I have `"hello":world.text`, where "world" is a UITextField? world.text returns String! (i.e. not a String)

Comment: Then declare _params:[String: String?] and always optionally unwrap its value

Comment: Very useful, thank you. It worked. Though unfortunately, when I provide `_params:[String String?]` to `Alamofire.request(.POST, _url, parameters: _params)`, I get "String? is not identical to 'AnyObject'"

Comment: Then declare _params:[String: String] and before adding value from uitextfield unwrap it like : if let text = world.text{ params["hello"] = text  }else{ params["hello"] = "" }

Answer (score 1):

Pasting your code into a playground is a pretty good way to help yourself debug. I took your code into my own playground and found the following to work:

```
import UIKit

func submitBoilerPlate(_url:String, _params:[String: String!], _button:UIButton?){
    var oldTitle = _button?.titleLabel?.text

    _button?.setTitle("Please wait...", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    _button?.enabled = false
}

var url:String = "https://eamorr.com/ajax/getLatestContent.php"
var params:[String: String!] = [
    "hello":"world"
]
submitBoilerPlate(url, params, nil)
```

Notice the explicit type of `params` and the removal of your `_params` and `_button` errors in the `submitBoilerPlate` call.

Specifying `params` without an explicit type was causing the compiler to not align your bits properly according to the required `[String: String!]` parameter type.

Having `_params` and `_button` as part of your function call is actually an error. When there's no space, there's no name to the parameters. An example of the alternative is:

```
func submitBoilerPlate(_url:String, someParams _params:[String: String!], andButton _button:UIButton?) {
  // .. same func body
}

submitBoilerPlate(url, someParams:params, andButton:nil)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. Trying to port an app from Objective-C to Swift here... Still on the learning curve...

Comment: What is it about my answer that does not solve your question, I wonder.